# How to keep the value of a DropDown after post in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 drop down list in MVC that after choosing their value and click on next button, it will post the data and show some text boxes with the value at the bottom of the page. When I click on the NEXT and it goes to POST method I get error as does not have ViewBag value. How I can keep the value of viewbag in Post method?

This is my index controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DAL.DataManager data = new DAL.DataManager();
        List<LALegalType> LegalData = new List<LALegalType>();

        //------------------------------Populate Entity Dropdown------------------------------------------//
          LegalData = data.get_LA_Get_Legal_Type_Xref("Entity");
          List<SelectListItem> listItem = createDropdowns(LegalData);

           ViewBag.DDLEnityValue = new SelectList(listItem, "Value", "Text");


 ...
 return View();
```

and this is my view:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Entity", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLEnityValue, new
                                    {
                                        @class = "validate[required]",
                                        tabindex = 1,
                                        required = true
                                    })

    }
```

and this is mt post method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, Compliance_FormField model)
    {



        Utilities.functions F = new Utilities.functions();
        string Entity = F.getControlValue(Request["Entity"]);
        .....
```

My Entity here does have a number of the dropdown not the value.

Comment: Why on earth are you creating a duplicate `SelectList` from the original one?  - it just needs to be `ViewBag.DDLEnityValue = createDropdowns(LegalData);` and change the view to `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DDLEnityValue`

Comment: And I assume you mean _has a value, not the text_. A `<select>` only posts back a single value (the value of the selected option), not its display text. If for some reason you need the object again, then you need to get it from your repository based on the selected value.

Answer (score 2):

If the post won't navigate the user to a new page then you have to rebind the drop down lists on your post action method. MVC doesn't have ViewState to preserve the state of your controls that's why it's required to maintain the state manually.

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, Compliance_FormField model)
{

Utilities.functions F = new Utilities.functions();
string Entity = F.getControlValue(Request["Entity"]);
//Rebind DDL's
//Add logic to rebind you dropdownlist and set selected item from you model            
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please do something like that. Just place the check of null for viewbag.DDLEnityValue like that in your cshtml page. And you will not face this issue anymore.

```
@{
      if( ViewBag.DDLEnityValue != null ) {

         Html.DropDownList("Entity", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLEnityValue, new
                                {
                                    @class = "validate[required]",
                                    tabindex = 1,
                                    required = true
                                })
         }
}
```